# How to disable Dragging in UITextView in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uitextview

I am using UITextview in UITableview with copy and link detection  for selection. Drag and drop is working without implementing Drag and drop feature on UITextview. So I want to disable UITextView drag and drop...

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059925/how-to-disable-ios-11-dragging-within-the-whole-app) can help to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 37):

To disable the text dragging (where the text "pops out" and can be dragged across the screen), try the following:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { 
    textView.textDragInteraction?.isEnabled = false 
}
```

Comment: How can we disable when someone drops in textfield? textDropInteraction doesn't work...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and have found a solution suitable for me.

So, I had a `TableView` with a single `TextView` inside every cell. I wanted to enable drag/drop for `TableView` in order to be able to move cells. But when I was long-pressing a cell, I was actually pressing its `TextView`, starting the drag session for it either. And whenever I tried to move that cell to a new position in `TableView`, the app was trying to insert the text from that cell's `TextView` to a new cell's `TextView`, performing a "drag and drop text copy operation".

In order to disable such kind of interaction you can try the following:

1. Make an extension for your UITableViewCell object (in *YourTableViewCell.swift* file, linked to *YourTableViewCell.xib*):

```swift
extension YourTableViewCell: UITextDropDelegate {
  func textDroppableView(_ textDroppableView: UIView & UITextDroppable, proposalForDrop drop: UITextDropRequest) -> UITextDropProposal {
    return UITextDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
  }
}
```

2. Make `YourTableViewCell` a drop delegate for a `TextView` (also in *YourTableViewCell.swift*)

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  YourTextView.textDropDelegate = self
}
```

Where `YourTextView` is an outlet for your cell's text view

This will help your app to stop trying to insert text inside `UITextView` in your `TableView`.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to **disable the drop interaction**,  check out the following lines,

```
print(noteView.interactions) // you will find a drop interaction here
textView.interactions.removeAll(where: { $0 is UIDropInteraction })
print(noteView.interactions) // it's gone
```

likewise, **both drag and drop interactions can be disabled/removed** like that

```
textView.interactions.removeAll(where: { $0 is UIDropInteraction
                                      || $0 is UIDragInteraction })
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable UITextview and UITextfield drop:

```
textView.removeInteraction(textView.textDropInteraction!)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hy, I tried a more simple solution, that seems to work :

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {      
    myTextView.textDropDelegate=nil
}
```

So now, when I drop an Image in this area, I can handle it as an Image and not as the text of the path.