# How to disable iOS 11 and iOS 12 Drag & Drop in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11, wkwebview

Long-pressing images or links in a `WKWebView` on iOS 11 and 12 initiates a Drag & Drop session (the user can drag the image or the link). How can I disable that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did find a [solution that involves method swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091497/171933) but it's also possible to disable drag and drop in a WKWebView without any swizzling.

**Note: See special notes for iOS 12.2+ below**

`WKContentView` — a private subview of `WKWebView`'s `WKScrollView` — has an `interactions` property, just like any other `UIView` in iOS 11+. That `interactions` property contains both a `UIDragInteraction` and a `UIDropInteraction`. Simply setting `enabled` to `false` on the `UIDragInteraction` does the trick.

We don't want to access any private APIs and make the code as solid as possible.

Assuming your `WKWebView` is called `webView`:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {        
    // Step 1: Find the WKScrollView - it's a subclass of UIScrollView
    UIView *webScrollView = nil;

    for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            webScrollView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (webScrollView) {
        // Step 2: Find the WKContentView
        UIView *contentView = nil;

        // We don't want to trigger any private API usage warnings, so instead of checking
        // for the subview's type, we simply look for the one that has two "interactions" (drag and drop)
        for (UIView *subview in webScrollView.subviews) {
            if ([subview.interactions count] > 1) {
                contentView = subview;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (contentView) {
            // Step 3: Find and disable the drag interaction
            for (id<UIInteraction> interaction in contentView.interactions) {
                if ([interaction isKindOfClass:[UIDragInteraction class]]) {
                    ((UIDragInteraction *) interaction).enabled = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!

### Special note for iOS 12.2+

The above code still works on iOS 12.2, but it is important *when* to call it. On iOS 12.1 and below you could call this code right after creating the `WKWebView`. That's not possible anymore. The `WKContentView`'s `interactions` array is empty when it's first created. It is only populated after the `WKWebView` is added to a view hierarchy that is attached to a `UIWindow` - simply adding it to a superview that is not yet part of the visible view hierarchy is not enough. In a view controller `viewDidAppear` would most likely be a safe place to call it from.

#### How did I find this out?

- I searched through the WebKit source and found this: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/65619d485251a3ffd87b48ab29b342956f3dcdc7/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/ios/WKContentViewInteraction.mm#L4953
- That's the method that creates and adds the `UIDragInteraction`
- It turns out that this method (`setupDataInteractionDelegates`) actually exists on `WKContentView`
- So I set a symbolic breakpoint on `-[WKContentView setupDataInteractionDelegates]`
- The breakpoint was hit
- I used lldb to print the backtrace using the `bt` command

This was the output:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 50.1  
  * frame #0: 0x00000001115b726c WebKit`-[WKContentView(WKInteraction) setupDataInteractionDelegates]  
    frame #1: 0x00000001115a8852 WebKit`-[WKContentView(WKInteraction) setupInteraction] + 1026  
    frame #2: 0x00000001115a5155 WebKit`-[WKContentView didMoveToWindow] + 79
```

So clearly the creation and addition of the `UIDragInteraction` is triggered by the view moving to (being added to) a window.

Answer (score 3):

This works great!
Thanks @basha for the swift version.

I did the same but with some compactMaps to reduce the depth of the if-statements and guards to get rid of the force unwraps.

```
private func disableDragAndDropInteraction() {
    var webScrollView: UIView? = nil
    var contentView: UIView? = nil

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        guard let noDragWebView = webView else { return }
        webScrollView = noDragWebView.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIScrollView }.first
        contentView = webScrollView?.subviews.first(where: { $0.interactions.count > 1 })
        guard let dragInteraction = (contentView?.interactions.compactMap { $0 as? UIDragInteraction }.first) else { return }
        contentView?.removeInteraction(dragInteraction)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using `first(where: ...)` instead of `compactMap(...).first`? I wonder because you're using it to look for `contentView`.

Comment: No particular resason, first(where:) would also do the trick.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for UITextView ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Johannes FahrenKrug's Post, with some changes.

```
private func disableDragAndDropInteraction() {
    var webScrollView: UIView? = nil
    var contentView: UIView? = nil

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if (webView != nil) {
            for subView in webView!.subviews {
                if (subView is UIScrollView) {
                    webScrollView = subView
                    break
                }
            }

            if (webScrollView != nil) {
                for subView in webScrollView!.subviews {
                    if subView.interactions.count > 1 {
                        contentView = subView
                        break
                    }
                }

                if (contentView != nil) {
                    for interaction in contentView!.interactions {
                        if interaction is UIDragInteraction {
                            contentView!.removeInteraction(interaction)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS property `webkit-touch-callout` on the `img` and `a` elements. Also set their `draggable` attribute to `false` by changing the HTML or injecting it using `-[WKWebView evaluateJavaScript(...)]`.

```
img, a {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

<img draggable="false">
```

Avoids all the fragile subview diving and manipulation.

(Recap of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489653/19255) to the similar [Disable link drag on WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538771/disable-link-drag-on-wkwebview) .)

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to subclass WKWebView and search the view hierarchy for subviews that contain drag or drop interactions, recursively. Once a view is found, which most likely will be a `WKContentView`, the interactions are removed. The benefit of this method is to not rely on any subview order / view hierarchy, which could change between OS releases.

```swift
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()
        
        disableDragAndDrop()
    }
    
    func disableDragAndDrop() {
        func findInteractionView(in subviews: [UIView]) -> UIView? {
            for subview in subviews {
                for interaction in subview.interactions {
                    if interaction is UIDragInteraction {
                        return subview
                    }
                }
                return findInteractionView(in: subview.subviews)
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        if let interactionView = findInteractionView(in: subviews) {
            for interaction in interactionView.interactions {
                if interaction is UIDragInteraction || interaction is UIDropInteraction {
                    interactionView.removeInteraction(interaction)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing. I'd consider using `interaction.enabled = false` instead of removing it, but I guess those are just two different ways to accomplish the same goal.