# Disable link drag on WKWebView

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, drag-and-drop

I'm using the newest version of Xcode and Swift. I'm using a programatically created WKWebView.

If I tap on a link, wait a second and then move my finger, I can drag (and then also drop) a small box with the links title and the link itself.

For clarification: I don't mean force touch, that will show a link preview and some actions like `Ad link to reading list`.

How can I disable the drag link behavior?

Comment: Why got my question downvoted and suggested for closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: [How to disable iOS 11 and iOS 12 Drag & Drop in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911060/how-to-disable-ios-11-and-ios-12-drag-drop-in-wkwebview/54668998#54668998)

This is my working code:

```
private func disableDragAndDropInteraction() {
    var webScrollView: UIView? = nil
    var contentView: UIView? = nil
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        guard let noDragWebView = webView else { return }
        webScrollView = noDragWebView.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIScrollView }.first
        contentView = webScrollView?.subviews.first(where: { $0.interactions.count > 1 })
        guard let dragInteraction = (contentView?.interactions.compactMap { $0 as? UIDragInteraction }.first) else { return }
        contentView?.removeInteraction(dragInteraction)
    }
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    disableDragAndDropInteraction()
}
```

You also have to add `disableDragAndDropInteraction()` after initialising `WKWebView`, e.g. in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: calling the function in viewDidLoad() was important, Thank You  ☺️

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the HTML loaded into the WKWebView, you can use the CSS property `webkit-touch-callout` like:

```
img, a {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

You also need to set the element's `draggable` attribute to `false`, like:

```
<img ... draggable="false">
```

I guess you could also inject these modifications using `-[WKWebView evaluateJavaScript(...)]` and family.

This'll avoid the need to rely on fragile subview diving and manipulation.

Tested as of iOS 15.3.

Here's some official (old) documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_touch_callout