# How to disable URL drag in a Capacitor application for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

I have an iOS app written using Capacitor.
I have buttons which are links to different part of the application.

If I do a long press over some button then drag it the iOS shows a popup block exposing the internal link, something like "capacitor://...."

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

I can change every link and replace `href` with onclick method but I wonder if there is an option somewhere in Xcode to do it for all links.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489653/6731412

Comment: Yes, it helped. Not a one-click solution, but at least it's easier than implementing onclick for every link.